# Tensor flow sigmoid function not working

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, sigmoid

I am new to tensor flow and Neural Networks.

In the code below,everything works fine. 
However as soon as I implement the tf.sigmoid function by uncommenting #X21 = tf.sigmoid(X21); I get weird results where in all my predictions are equal to 1. Any reason why this might be happening?

Note that I am predicting house prices which are in thousands.

```
# Set model weights
b1_1 = tf.cast(tf.Variable(np.random.randn(), name="bias"),tf.float64)
b1_2 = tf.cast(tf.Variable(np.random.randn(), name="bias"),tf.float64)
b2_1 = tf.cast(tf.Variable(np.random.randn(), name="bias"),tf.float64)

W1_1 = tf.cast(tf.Variable(np.random.randn(train_X.shape[1], 1), name="bias"),tf.float64)
W1_2 = tf.cast(tf.Variable(np.random.randn(train_X.shape[1], 1), name="bias"),tf.float64)
W2_1 = tf.cast(tf.Variable(np.random.randn(2, 1), name="bias"),tf.float64)

X11 = tf.add(tf.matmul(train_X,W1_1),b1_1)
X12 = tf.add(tf.matmul(train_X,W1_2),b1_2)
X21 = tf.add(tf.matmul(tf.squeeze(tf.transpose(tf.stack((X11,X12)))),W2_1),b2_1)
#X21 = tf.sigmoid(X21)

# placeholders for a tensor that will be always fed.
Y = tf.placeholder('float64', shape = [47, 1])

cost = (tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(X21-Y, 2))/(2*n_samples))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)

# Initialize the variables (i.e. assign their default value)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

# Start training
with tf.Session() as sess:

    # Run the initializer
    sess.run(init)

    # Fit all training data
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        #for (x, y) in zip(train_X, train_Y):
        sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={Y: train_Y})
                # Display logs per epoch step
        if (epoch+1) % display_step == 0:
            c = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={Y: train_Y})
            print("Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch+1), "cost=", "{:.9f}".format(c))

    print("Optimization Finished!")

    training_cost = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={Y: train_Y})
    print("Training cost=", training_cost)
    line = sess.run(X21,feed_dict={Y: train_Y})
```

Comment: Sigmoid function, by its definition, produces values between -1 and 1. And it is intended to be used with data normalized to value between -1 and 1, because outside of this range it asymptotically approaches either its minimum or its maximum. So if you feed large positive values into it you will get all 1s (or rather almost 1s).

Comment: Machine learning is mathematically intensive and algorithms are very data sensitive. If you want to make a quick ML solution, I suggest you use a higher level API of some sort (recent versions of Tensorflow has some pretty good high level APIs). But if you want to implement your own ML algorithms, you want to pay more attention to the underlying math and make sure you understand why each step you make is needed.

Comment: My bad, tanh produces values from (-1, 1), sigmoid produces (0, 1)

Comment: Oh yes! Sorry, my bad too. So, I have to predict house prices on the basis of size of the room and area. How do you think I can improve the predictions? What are the areas in the above code that I can play with to improve it?

Comment: Your output layer doesn't need an activation function (especially, since you are going to predict actual prices). But your hidden layers might benefit. Try to add sigmoid to X11 and X12 and leave X21 as is. Try to switch from plain SGD optimizer to Adam or RPSProp.

Another idea is to split the prices you want to predict into several price categories or classes and instead of trying to predict exact prices, try to predict the category.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. AdamOptimizer really worked. I was consistently underpredicting in some areas earlier, but using AdamOptimizer really solved the issue.

Comment: I am trying to understand what is the difference between these optimizers and which one is the best to use in which situation. I am looking into TF website, but if you know of place where these are explained in a better and easy to understand way, let me know. Also, I tried to change the hidden layer using sigmoid, but that gave all the predictions as 1.422. Any idea why this might be happening?